# Factorial Java Program

Tags: java, for-loop, factorial

I want to do a factorial program in java using a for loop. For example I want to take the user input, lets say `10`, and then multiply `10*9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1`. I need help constructing the `for` loop. The code below is all I have so far as I'm not sure where to go after.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math;
public class factorial {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        num = input.nextInt();
    }
}
```

Comment: now that you have the number your user input in your program, you need to compute "in some way" to calculate the factorial.

Comment: Recommended reading: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int num;
    int fact=1;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    num = input.nextInt();
    for (int i=2;i<=num; i++){
        fact=fact*i;
    }

    System.out.println("Factorial: "+fact);
}
```

As @Marko Topolnik mentioned in comments this code will work for inputs up to 12. For larger inputs will output infinity due to overflow.

For numbers larger than 12 you should use higher data type like `BigInteger`

You can try:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    BigInteger num;
    BigInteger fact = BigInteger.valueOf(1);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
    num = input.nextBigInteger();
    for (int i = 2; i <= num; i++){
        fact = fact.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
    }
    System.out.println(fact);
}
```

Comment: The point of homework assignments like this is not to get a student to memorize syntax, but to work through the process of breaking a problem down into smaller pieces and approaching each piece by itself. By posting a full-code solution, you've robbed the OP of that process, which is going to hurt him/her in the long run. What happens the next time the OP has to solve a problem? What happens during a test? Recommended reading: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Note that your code only works for inputs up to 12. A bound check would probably be a good idea...

Comment: @KevinWorkman The factorial-computing code is not exactly classified information. All laaposto did was rob OP of an attempt at googling it. You may attack him on moral grounds, but not of leaking a big secret.

Comment: @KevinWorkman my teacher has mental issues and is being fired after this year, my class has had to try to learn on our own and it is resulting in bad results. "If you can find it on the internet, you can use it" - My teacher

Comment: @Iaaposto Okay, will do.

Comment: @Eqorip While I sympathize with your situation, keep in mind that plenty of people learned programming completely on their own, without the benefits of a classroom, classmates, tutoring sessions, school library, or any of the other perks that come with being in a classroom. Feel free to use the full-code solution, but I'll warn you that 90% of programming is working through a problem, breaking it down into smaller pieces, and approaching each piece independently. Memorizing syntax is the other 10%. Good luck.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Not everyone can learn in that fashion, and if I could, I would have a long time ago because I've tried. I took this class in order to learn for that exact reason.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I've been making a factorial calculator and every piece of code that I've tried breaks for every number larger than 12. Is there a fix for that?

Comment: Nice OP. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

## Coding by Recursive function:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
         Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
         int num = input.nextInt();
         long factorialResult = factorialRecursive(num);
         System.out.println(factorialResult);
     }


     public static long factorialRecursive(int n) {
         if (n == 0 || n == 1 )
             return 1;

         return n * factorialRecursive(n - 1);
     }
}
```

source: [learn.uncox.com](http://learn.uncox.com/android/%D8%A8%D8%AE%D8%B4-2-%D9%85%D9%82%D8%AF%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%AA-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D9%86%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%87-%D9%86%D9%88%DB%8C%D8%B3%DB%8C-%D8%AC%D8%A7%D9%88%D8%A7)

If the number is large, "stackoverflow" happens.

Comment: The factorial of 0 is 1. Your code doesn't account for that. Base case should be `n == 0`

Answer (score 3):

Why bother computing it?

```
public int factorial ( int n ) {
switch(n){
case 0: return 1;
case 1: return 1;
case 2: return 2;
case 3: return 6;
case 4: return 24;
case 5: return 120;
case 6: return 720;
case 7: return 5040;
case 8: return 40320;
case 9: return 362880;
case 10: return 3628800;
case 11: return 39916800;
case 12: return 479001600;
default : throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

Source : [@Emory](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/16673/8806)

Comment: Nice :) Way to cheat the system xD

Comment: Exactly---a lookup table is all you really need. And for a `long` result the size of the cascade will just double.

Comment: I think you just computed it yourself 12 times..  That's why we code, to prevent doing tedious stuff :D  (or did you write code to calculate it?)

Comment: @RobAu The reasoning is that there's too few cases to bother running the calculations every time the user asks for a factorial

Answer (score 2):

This is My Program

```
class FactorialUsingFor
{
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        int factorial = 1;
        int number = 6;

        for(int i = 1; i <= number; i++)
        {
            factorial *= i;
        }

        System.out.println("Factorial of number " + number + " is " + factorial);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int sum = 1;

for (int i = 2;i <= num;i++) {
    sum = sum * i;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this program:=

```
import java.util.*;
public class Factorials {
 public static void main(String[] args){
  Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
  int i,num,a,b;
  int c=1;
  System.out.println("Enter the no.= ");
  num=sc.nextInt();
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
   c=i*c;
  }
  System.out.println("Factorial is "+c);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Factorial {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number to find factorial");
        int o=scn.nextInt();
        int count=0,b=o-1,res=(o*(o-1)),r=0;
        while(count!=1)
        {
         count=b-1;
         r=count*res;
         res=r;
         r=1;
         b=b-1;
        }
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int factorialLoop(int val) {
     
     int result = 1 ;
    
    for (int i = val ; i>= 1 ; i--){
        
        result =  result * i ;
        
    }
    
    return result ;
    
}

int factorielRecursive(int val){ 
    
   if(1 <= val){
    
     return val*factorialRecursive(val-1);
     
   }else {
    
    return 1;
    
   }
    
}
```