# Given number n, find the factorial of that number

Tags: java

**Output** is wrong it just *multiplying second number* with itself.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class trybew {

    void factorial(int n) {

        long fact = 1;
        for(int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
        fact *=  n;
        System.out.println(" "+fact);
    }
    }
     public static void main(String[] args) {
       int cnt;
        trybew f1= new trybew();
        Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Test case ");
        cnt=s.nextInt();
        int n[]= new int[cnt];
        for(int i=0; i<cnt; i++) {
        System.out.println("ENter NO:: ");
        n[i]=s.nextInt();
        }
        for(int i=0; i<cnt; i++)
        f1.factorial(n[i]);
    }

}
```

Comment: `fact *=  n;` must be `fact *=  i;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Factorial Java Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482785/factorial-java-program)

Answer (score 0):

```
void factorial(int n) {

    long fact = 1;
    for(int i=n; i>=1; i--) 
        fact *=  i;
    System.out.println(" "+fact);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is with your code `fact *=  n;` . You are supposed to use  `i` here. 
Change

```
fact *=  n;
```

To

```
fact *=  i;
```

Modified code :-

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class trybew {

    void factorial(int n) {

        long fact = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            fact *= i;  // not *=n
            System.out.println(" " + fact);
        }
    }

    public static void trybew(String[] args) {
        int cnt;
        trybew f1 = new trybew();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Test case ");
        cnt = s.nextInt();
        int n[] = new int[cnt];
        for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
            System.out.println("ENter NO:: ");
            n[i] = s.nextInt();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++)
            f1.factorial(n[i]);
    }

}
```

Output :-

```
Enter Test case 

2
ENter NO:: 
4
ENter NO:: 
5
 1
 2
 6
 24
 1
 2
 6
 24
 120
```

It is better to use `System.out.println(" " + fact);` outside the `for-loop` in function `void factorial(int n)` .