# find number by given factorial number

Tags: java

I need to find number by given factorial number. I know how to find factorial of a number .But stuck to find number of given factorial..

```
class Fact{  
 public static void main(String args[]){  
  int i,fact=1;  
  int number=5;  
  for(i=1;i<=number;i++){    
      fact=fact*i;    
  }    
  int yo = number(number);
  System.out.println(fact + " " + yo );   

 }  

  public static int number(int no){
      for(int i = 1 ; i >= no ; i--){
          no = no / i;
      }
      return no;
  }
}
```

Comment: You should `return i`, not `return no`. So you'll have to declare `i` outside of that `for` loop. You might also want to verify that `no == 1` before returning (otherwise the input is not a factorial of any integer).

Comment: Second thought, your whole code is fundamentally wrong in several other places. For example, you're initializing `i = 1`, then checking if it's larger than `no`, which it is obviously not going to be!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Factorial Java Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21482785/factorial-java-program)

Comment: please use a debugger, to step through your code and inspect the values of the variables, then you will see why this is not working, especially the for-loop in then `number()`method

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your goal correctly, here the code you are looking for:

```
class Fact {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n = 5;

        int fact = factorial(n);
        int number = number(fact);

        System.out.println(n + " "+fact + " " + number);
    }

    public static int factorial(int n) {
        int fact = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            fact = fact * i;
        }
        return fact;
    }

    public static int number(int factorial) {
        int i = 0;
        do {
            i++;
            factorial = factorial / i;
        } while (factorial > 1);
        return i;
    }
}
```

output:

```
5 120 5
```

P.S. function `number` doesn't work correctly for argument `n! = 1` bc this fuction has two possible results - 0, 1 (see the table of results here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial ) and for `n >= 14` due to integer overflow. `number` returns correct number only for factorial passed.

Comment: Did you test for `number(119)`?

Comment: @forpas no, overflow it is another problem

Comment: This is not about overflow. Your `number(119)` returns `5`. Is `5! = 119`?

Comment: @forpas sorry. But why do I need to try ```number(119)```? The asker wants 'to find number of given factorial'  = here the code. There is no check for the passed number for factorial.

Comment: *I need to find number by given factorial number* means I want to check if a number is another number's factorial, or not?

Comment: @forpas not, does it?

Answer (score 0):

This method:

```
public static int number(int factorial) {
    if (factorial <= 0) return -1;
    if ((factorial == 1) || (factorial == 2)) return factorial;
    if (factorial % 2 != 0) return -1;

    int i = 1;
    int prod = 1;
    while (prod < factorial) {
        prod *= ++i;
    }
    return (prod == factorial) ? i : -1;
}
```

takes as an argument an integer number `factorial` and checks if it is the factorial of an integer and returns that integer. 
It is limited up to `12!` (this is the limit posed by the `int` data type)
For `1` as the argument it returns `1` and not `0` which is also a solution since `0! = 1`. 
It returns `-1` if it is not the factorial of an integer.
So, this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = -1; i <= 1_000_000_000; i++) {
        int x = number(i);
        if (x > 0)
            System.out.println("Number = " + i + " is the factorial of " + x);
    }
}
```

will print:

```
Number = 1 is the factorial of 1
Number = 2 is the factorial of 2
Number = 6 is the factorial of 3
Number = 24 is the factorial of 4
Number = 120 is the factorial of 5
Number = 720 is the factorial of 6
Number = 5040 is the factorial of 7
Number = 40320 is the factorial of 8
Number = 362880 is the factorial of 9
Number = 3628800 is the factorial of 10
Number = 39916800 is the factorial of 11
Number = 479001600 is the factorial of 12
```

I'm not sure if it's the most efficient way of doing this, but it gives correct results.

Comment: its go to infinte loop not stoping

Comment: In my code? No it does not. It is tested. If you test it in your code, you must know that there is a limit.

Comment: @VivekModi if this answer solved the problem, consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class FindNumber{
        public static void main(String args[]){
            int num,fact=1,i;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

            num = sc.nextInt();
            if(num<=0){
                System.out.println("Invalid Input");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            if(num==1){
                System.out.println("1");
                System.exit(0);
            }
if(num==2){
System.out.println("2");
System.exit(0);
}

            for(i=1;i<=num/2;i++){
                fact = fact*i;

                if(fact==num){
                    System.out.println(""+i);
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Sorry. The given number is not a perfect factorial");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide with a little text to explain why this works? (Except for the value of 2, but that's easily fixed)

Comment: If we input a value other than 1 and 2 assuming it is a perfect factorial, once in the for loop we start iterating it repeatedly multiplying 1 by the consecutive number and update fact at each iteration. Thus, if fact does become equal to the number input , the number is the number of iterations it took for fact to become this number input.

Comment: Your solution is very fast. I ran it. Please edit your answer instead of explaining in the comment, also with an example of how to run it. Then I think it will be more likely that your Question will be marked useful. You can reply to me here after, then I will remove my suggestions, so your Answer is clean :)